# JSONPath to get parameter from an array

Tags: jsonpath

I have a response body I believe is an array it looks like this:

{"id":982,"form_stage":"1","customer_hash":"fffae165253f494a95bdb753ca87716c"}

In this case I want to get "customer_hash" and I have tried every combination of $..customer_hash $.customer_hash, etc but none of them work because this doesn't start with "response" or "result" I guess it is an array not an object(?).

Can anyone tell me what would be the JSONPath mapping to get the parameter "customer_hash"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
$.customer_hash
```

Output:

```
 [
  "fffae165253f494a95bdb753ca87716c"
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing this originally but their "test" button was not actually performing the map, so I thought it was not working, finally I had to actually run the code outside of test mode to see the mapping was working all along.